# Unit of a log normal probability density function

Tags: probability, dimensional-analysis, units

How do I find the unit of a log-normal probability density function?

Comment: What do you mean the "unit" of the lognormal PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The units of a probability density function (PDF) for a quantity $x$, are the inverse of the units of $x$. For example, if $x$ has units of length, then the PDF $P(x)$ has units of 1/length, so that the probability $P(x) dx$ is dimensionless.

The fact that the functional form of the PDF may be a log-normal distribution is not relevant to the dimensions of the PDF.

Note, that the acronym PDF can also refer to a probability **distribution** function, in the context of discrete random variables. Of course, a log-normal distribution is continuous so your question presumably refers to probability density functions. Nevertheless, to avoid confusion, as pointed out by @JohnDarby, in the context of discrete random variables, the probability distribution function is dimensionless, because it gives dimensionless probabilities for each possible outcome.

Comment: This is true for a continuous random variable. The PDF for a discrete random variable is itself dimensionless, since for discrete variable R with PDF p, the probability R is r is p(R) a dimensionless probability.

Comment: @JohnDarby It's good to point out the difference between discrete and continuous probability distributions. But, the term PDF is only used for continuous distributions.

Comment: I see your point and will clarify my answer. What name would you suggest for a discrete variable? "Probability mass function" is used in some references I have for a discrete random variable.  "Probability density function" seems to always be used for a continuous variable, but it is sometimes loosely used for a discrete variable also.

Comment: @JohnDarby Actually looking this up it looks like there are two terms that have the acronym PDF. The probability **density** function is for continuous random variables, while the probability **distribution** function is for discrete random variables. I'll be honest, I have never heard of the probability distribution function (or if I had I forgot), I've always just called this "the probability of a given outcome" or something like that. I'll update my answer to clarify (and also +1 to your answer, which is making a good point). Very interesting!

Answer (score 4):

Consider any *continuous* random variable $V$ with the probability density function $p_V$. For $v$ any specific value of $V$, $p_{V}(v)$ is not a probability. The probability a specific value of $V$ is exactly $v$ is always zero and is meaningless; what is meaningful is the probability that $V$ is within $dv$ about $v$ and that probability is $p_V(v)dv$ which is always dimensionless regardless of the units of V as it must be since it is a probability.  So the units of $p_{v}$ are the inverse units of $V$.  See the earlier answer by @Andrew.

For a *discrete* random variable $R$ with probability density $p_{R}$, the probability that $R$ is the specific value $r$ is $p_{R}(r)$. $p_{R}$ for a discrete variable is the "probability mass function" sometimes called the "probability density function" and it always dimensionless regardless of the units of R as it must be since it is a probability.

A log-normal distribution is a special case. A log-normal distribution for the continuous random variable $X$ means that the logarithm of $X$ is normally distributed.  If $Y=ln(X)$ and Y is normally distributed, then the distribution for $X$ is a log-normal distribution.  The variable Y is dimensionless since it is the logarithm of a number. So, the probability density function $p_{Y}$ is also dimensionless for this special case. $X$ can have dimensions, so the units of $p_{X}$ are the inverse units of $X$.